# How to display data from a service in a mat table using reactive forms?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-material-table

I have the following table where the objective is to show the data from a service and to allow the fields to be edited, so it uses components such as mat input and mat select, so that the user can modify what is displayed from the service.

I have my html but when loading the screen it does not show the data of the service, when displaying the mat select, it does show the information, but it does not show by default the value that it brings from the database

```
     <mat-accordion class="example-headers-align" multi>
            <mat-expansion-panel>
                <mat-expansion-panel-header>
                    <mat-panel-title class="text">
                       Productos
                    </mat-panel-title>
                </mat-expansion-panel-header>
                <div class="scrollme">
                    <form [formGroup]="productosForm">
                        <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">

                            <ng-container matColumnDef="cveProducto">
                                <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> PRODUCTO </th>
                                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.cveProducto}} </td>
                            </ng-container>

                            <ng-container matColumnDef="idProd">
                                <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> TIPO </th>
                                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
                                    <mat-form-field>
                                        <mat-select [(value)]="element.idProd" class="select-css"
                                            formControlName="idProd">
                                            <mat-option *ngFor="let tipo of tipoModelo" [value]="tipo.idProd">
                                                {{tipo.descTipo}}
                                            </mat-option>
                                        </mat-select>
                                    </mat-form-field>
                                </td>
                            </ng-container>
                            
                            <ng-container matColumnDef="idGrupo">
                                <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> GRUPO </th>
                                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
                                    <mat-form-field>
                                        <mat-select [(value)]="element.idGrupo" class="select-css"
                                            formControlName="idGrupo">
                                            <mat-option *ngFor="let grupo of gpoModelo" [value]="grupo.idGrupo">
                                                {{grupo.descGpo}}
                                            </mat-option>
                                        </mat-select>
                                    </mat-form-field>
                                </td>
                            </ng-container>

                            <ng-container matColumnDef="descripcionProducto">
                                <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> DESCRIPCIÓN </th>
                                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
                                    <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
                                        <input matInput [value]="element.descripcionProducto" formControlName="descripcionProducto">
                                    </mat-form-field>
                                </td>
                            </ng-container>

                            <ng-container matColumnDef="claveUb">
                                <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> CLAVE </th>
                                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
                                    <mat-form-field>
                                        <mat-select formControlName="claveUb">
                                            <mat-option *ngFor="let ubix of cveUbix" [value]="ubix.valor">
                                                {{ubix.label}}
                                            </mat-option>
                                        </mat-select>
                                    </mat-form-field>
                                </td>
                            </ng-container>
                            <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
                            <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns">
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </mat-expansion-panel>
        </mat-accordion>
```

component.ts

```
displayedColumns: string[] = ['cveProducto', 'idProd', 'idGrupo','descripcionProducto', 'claveUb'];
     productoModelo: Producto[] = [];
     tipoModelo: TipoProducto[] = [];
     gpoModelo: GpoProducto[] = [];
  
        
    ngOnInit(): void {
    this.obtenerProductos();
    this.obtenerGpos();
    this.obtenerTipos();

    this.productosForm = new FormGroup({
      idProd: new FormControl(''),
      idGrupo: new FormControl(''),
      descripcionProducto: new FormControl(''),
      claveUb: new FormControl(''),
    })
  }

  cveUbix = [
    { label: 'Si', valor: 1 },
    { label: 'No', valor: 0 },
  ];


  dataSource: any;
  obtenerProductos() {
    this.productService.obtenerProducto().subscribe(response => {
      if (response.data.length == 0) {
        Swal.fire({
          icon: 'error',
          text: 'Sin datos para mostrar'
        })
      } else {
        this.productoModelo = response.data;
        this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.productoModelo);
        this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
      }

    });
  }

  dataSourceTipoProd: any;
  obtenerTipos() {
    this.productService.obtenerTiposProd().subscribe(response => {
      if (response.data.length == 0) {
        Swal.fire({
          icon: 'error',
          text: 'Sin datos para mostrar'
        })
      } else {
        this.tipoModelo = response.data;
        this.dataSourceTipoProd = new MatTableDataSource(this.tipoModelo);
        this.dataSourceTipoProd.paginatorCatalogos = this.paginatorCatalogos;
      }

    });
  }

  dataSourceGpoProd: any;
  obtenerGpos() {
    this.productService.obtenerGpoProd().subscribe(response => {
      if (response.data.length == 0) {
        Swal.fire({
          icon: 'error',
          text: 'Sin datos para mostrar'
        })
      } else {
        this.gpoModelo = response.data;
        this.dataSourceGpoProd = new MatTableDataSource(this.gpoModelo);
        this.dataSourceGpoProd.paginatorCatalogos = this.paginatorCatalogos;
      }

    });
  }
```

What do I have to change or what am I missing so that when loading the page, the table shows me the data of the service?
What is the right way

Answer (score 0):

Di you check that your service is getting the correct data to display?
You can use the "safe Navigation operator"

```
<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element?.cveProducto}} </td>
```